# Cannot finish a child tab activity before it starts

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have a `TabActivity` that is my `MainActivity`, it has two tabs that are `tab1` and `tab2`.

By default `MainActivity` starts with the `tab1` In front.

When i click on the `tab2`, the `tab2` must start an intent back into the `MainActivity` after that the `tab2` activity must finish, all of that should happen before the `setContent(R.layout.tab2)` is executed.

The application behavior I'm trying to get is, every time that i click on `tab2`, the application should back to `tab1`.

This works fine, but the problem is, the content of `tab2` appears for few seconds before the `tab2` activity is finished and the intent is started into `MainActivity`.

I know about the setCurrentTab method, but it's not what I'm Looking for.

Here is my `tab2` Activity:

```
public class tab2 extends Activity
{   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    if(true)

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.tab2);` . i.e if you don't set any view then no view would be shown. I haven't tried it but it seems that it would work.

**Update**

As you said in comments that If sometime condition can be false then have it inside if condition:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if(conditions_is_true){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}else{
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
}
```

Comment: That's not at solution for me, because, on my real application, the condition could be false sometimes.